# Method overloading with empty String(null/"") and String

Tags: java

just signed up and this is my first question. I did try to search for it here and on Google but could not find a relevant answer. Most of the answers (and a lot of duplicate questions) were about Java choosing between Object and String (and Integer sometimes) as default for null value.

I am trying to overload method with String argument where method without argument is called when there is no input (empty String or ""). Basically, it's a simple scoreboard and I want to record score only if player enter their name at the end of the game, otherwise just display existing scoreboard. However, even with an empty String, user entry is still added. I understand that I can create two different methods, but I am trying to learn and implement method overloading. 'listScoreBoard' is the two-dimensional ArrayList used for adding and displaying scoreboard.

```
public static void displayScore (String playerName) {
    listScoreBoard.add(Arrays.asList(playerName, playerScore));
    displayScore();
}

public static void displayScore() {
    System.out.println(listScoreBoard);
}
```

I am very new to Java and programming (first semester in college), so apologies if this is a very simple question.

Comment: `String` objects have an `.isEmpty()` method...

Comment: If you are new to Java, this webpage is your best friend now - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: This is not really a good example of method overloading, since the two methods do quite different things. It would be better to name the first method something like "addAndDisplayScore".

Comment: @FredK I originally had two methods, one for adding score and one for displaying score while displayScore method was being called at the end of addScore. Just thought it might be a good idea to combine and overload them, I guess I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between calling a string without an argument vs with a *null* or *empty* argument. When you call the method without providing any argument, it will use the method that does not have an argument. When you call the method with *null* or *empty string* then it will use the method that takes a String argument.

```
displayScore(null); // This calls displayScore (String playerName)
displayScore(""); // This calls displayScore (String playerName)

displayScore(); // This calls displayScore ()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I do understand the difference. I was just wondering if there is a solution other then implementing two separates methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

if you call ,

```
displayScore("somestring") // first method is called
displayScore("") // first method is called
displayScore(null) // first method is called

displayScore() // second method is called
```

so to get the second method called, you have to call with no argument. that means whenever you pass `null`, or empty(`""`) or some string the first method is called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I do understand the difference. I was just wondering if there is a solution other then implementing two separates methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

Add condition which will check if no playerName is passed this will bypass adding to listScoreBoard.

```
public static void displayScore (String playerName) {
if (playerName != null && !playerNamer.trim().isEmpty())
    listScoreBoard.add(Arrays.asList(playerName, playerScore));
displayScore();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to overload method with String argument where method without argument is called when there is no input (empty String or "")

It is the compiler that chooses at compile-time which of the two methods should be called. Overloaded method selection is not determined at run-time.

Since the compiler doesn't know the value at runtime, *you* have to code the logic of calling the no-arg overload when the string is null or empty.

```
public static void displayScore(String playerName) {
    if (playerName == null || playerName.isEmpty()) {
        displayScore();
        return;
    }
    listScoreBoard.add(Arrays.asList(playerName, playerScore));
    displayScore();
}

public static void displayScore() {
    System.out.println(listScoreBoard);
}
```

Or, since you call `displayScore()` even for non-empty input:

```
public static void displayScore(String playerName) {
    if (playerName != null && ! playerName.isEmpty()) {
        listScoreBoard.add(Arrays.asList(playerName, playerScore));
    }
    displayScore();
}

public static void displayScore() {
    System.out.println(listScoreBoard);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I previously had the logic implemented at the end of the game depending on player input and had two separate methods for adding and displaying scores. I guess that would be a better than unnecessarily overloading methods and coding my logic there if I had to do it manually anyway?